# Solving $y_1=a\ln(b x_1)$ and $y_2=a\ln(b x_2)$ for $a$ and $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Maths found from another post:

[image]

How is a and b equated? I don't understand the method and am hoping someone is able to help and show the process.

Comment: To be clear: Are you asking how to solve the equations to get $a$ and $b$? Have you found $a$ and $b$ in other forms and want to know how to get the forms given? Something else? ... In any case, please show the work you've done and where you got stuck. This will help people understand exactly what you need while avoiding explaining things you already understand.

Comment: So I have the answer in that form but am not able to understand how they found that. So I want help to figure out how they solved those equations to find a and b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to solve the system

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
y_1 & = & a \ln(bx_1) \\
y_2 & = & a \ln(bx_2) 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

The key point is to notice that, once $a$ is determined, we can easily obtain $b$ since

$$
y=a\ln(ax) \iff \frac{y}{a}=\ln(bx) \iff bx = \exp\left(\frac{y}{a}\right) \iff b = \frac{\exp(y/a)}{x}
$$

To find $a$, assume first that $x_1\neq x_2$. Subtracting the two equations, we get

$$y_1-y_2= a\left(\ln(bx_1)-\ln(bx_2)\right)=a\ln\left(\frac{bx_1}{bx_2}\right)=a\ln\left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right)$$

so $$a=\frac{y_1-y_2}{\ln\left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right)}
=\frac{y_1-y_2}{\ln(x_1)-\ln(x_2)}$$

This implies that

$$
\frac{y_1}{a} = \frac{y_1\ln(x_1)-y_1\ln(x_1)}{y_1-y_2}
$$

so

$$
b = \frac{\exp\left(\frac{y_1\ln(x_1)-y_1\ln(x_1)}{y_1-y_2}\right)}{x_1}
$$

To obtain the formula from the answer in the OP, we can write $x_1=\exp(\ln(x_1))$ and we get

$$
b 
= 
\frac{\exp\left(\frac{y_1\ln(x_1)-y_1\ln(x_1)}{y_1-y_2}\right)}{\exp(\ln(x_1))}
=
\exp\left(\frac{y_1\ln(x_1)-y_1\ln(x_1)}{y_1-y_2}-\ln(x_1)\right)
$$

Finally,

$$
b=
\exp\left(\frac{y_1\ln(x_1)-y_1\ln(x_1)-(y_1-y_2)\ln(x_1)}{y_1-y_2}\right)
=
\exp\left(\frac{y_1\ln(x_2)-y_2\ln(x_1)}{y_1-y_2}\right)
$$

If $x_1=x_2$, then $y_1\neq y_2$, so the system has no solution.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if you like it